# Docker docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ scripts with Mongodb aren't working

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have been struggling to configure the execution of scripts via /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d in a Mongo container in Docker.

I have tried to follow the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) carefully, but without success.

***project structure***

[image]

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo_db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: database
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
      - ./init.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    restart: always
volumes:
  mongodbdata:
    driver: local
```

***init-mongo.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello script'
```

In the logs the command echo 'hello script' is not executed.

What should I do? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker only executes scripts inside `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` upon creation of the image as this is mostly used for seeding data. If it's not a fresh image and you're just trying to spawn it again with your script then that's what caused it.

What you can try to do is type this in your terminal:

`docker stop $(docker ps -aq) && docker rm $(docker ps -aq) && docker rmi mongo:latest -f && docker-compose up`

Then check the logs :P

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. I have removed the images. I have also used the command you provided. But still without success. =(

Comment: did you try to check within the image if the script actually exists inside the initdb directory?

Comment: Ahh I think i know the problem. can you try to switch it to /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash? then use the command again I provided. since most images don't have bash. @Xenetrix

Comment: The truth is I've checked everything again, besides applying your suggestions and I still can't find the problem. What I'm looking for is to use the script to initialize my mogodb database, but I can't move forward if I don't solve the execution problem first.

Comment: Its strange, sometimes the script works, and sometimes not... but your answer is perfect.

Comment: Good to hear @Xenetrix, probably because of the second to the last command I gave `docker rmi mongo:latest -f` better change the `mongo:latest` to the specific image id.